# Person to Address JPA mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, database-design, jpa, orm

A person's address may look as the following:

```
country: USA
state: Some state
city: N.Y.
Street: some stree name with buildings
Building: number of the building on the street
```

Or as an alternative if building consists of several apartments/rooms another entity should  be used:

> Apartments/rooms: number of the apartment in the building

every next level in the example has the parent one as a foreing key that cannot be null:

county - is a container of states

state - is a container of cities and so one.

building - may be or may be not a container of rooms/apartments.

As a result I have the following tables for each level:

```
country
id   name
1    USA

state
id  country_id name
2       1      N.Y.

city
id  state_id   name
3       2      New York

Street 
id  city_id    name
4       3      Some Street Name

Building
id  street_id  number
5       4       28

apartment
id  building_id number
8       5         36
```

The problem I've met is how to map person to this tables structure? 
Person may or may not live in an apartment, if it's a big family house for instance.
Ideally I'd like to have a collection of some entities:

```
ManyToMany
Collection<SomeEntity> addresses ...
```

where `SomeEntity` can refer either to an apartment or to a building directly.

Here are options I'm considering now, but I don't like them.

The first option where `SomeEntity` will have a type - either building or apartment and it will look like:

```
SomeEntity 
id person_id type       address_id
10    11     building     21
11    13     apartment    24
```

where in the first case it address_id refers to the building table, in the second one - to the apartment table.

The second option is to have a table that have the following list of fields:

```
SomeEntity
id  person_id  country_id  state_id city_id street_id building_id apartment_id
```

In this case, if a bulding has no rooms, the apartment_id field is null. Also it's useful if I need for example to get list of persons who live in the city/or on the street cause I don't need to join all address-related tables, just refer to SomeEntity table. What do you think about this table? How to map the Person object in this case? SomeEntity - is just a table, not the object. My services actually should not know anything about internal tables structure. This issue is not clear to me. Probably you can offer the better solution.

Please, help.

Comment: My first question would be: what are you using these addresses for? Why is it important to know that a person lives in a given apartment or building, and even in a given street? Couldn't you simply have line1, line2, postal code, city, [state] and country, for example?

Comment: why didnt you make table SomeEntity that have column of `id building_id apartment_id(nullable)` then you can use it to get your "person.addresses.building" or "person.addresses.apartment"

Comment: @Angga, my second solution - is something similar you offer. How to map objects in this case?

Answer (score 0):

if something similar to my comment is your solution then what you asked is how to map join in hibernate.
it will be something like this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEST_TABLE_A")
public class TestTableA {
    public TestTableA(){

    }
    public TestTableA(String aName){
        this.aName = aName;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "A_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "A_NAME")
    private String aName;

    //some other atribut here

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinTable(name="A_JOIN_B",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="A_ID")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="B_ID")})
    private Set<TestTableB> testJoins = new HashSet<TestTableB>();
    //Getters and setters of all the collumn here
}
```

you can assume the TEST_TABLE_A is your BUILDING table in your database, and TestTableB is your apartment entity. and A_JOIN_B is your SOME_ENTITY table, and testJoins is the object you are looking for. You must get that object from the Building through.

You may want to change the relationship to @OneToMany if you want. and change the `Cascade.Type` [(detail about cascade)](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-cascade-example-save-update-delete-and-delete-orphan/) so it will be easier for you to maintain that table.